# org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo unable to recycle, large number of instances found in memory

Tags: jvm, heap-memory

In a JVM tuning, I found that regardless of the data, and heap memory will overflow, heap dump pictures as shown in figure, org. Apache. Coyote. RequestInfo exist a large collection of instance, in the younger generation is not recycled into old age and recycling

[image]